# Moment.js: Date between dates

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to detect with Moment.js if a given date is between two dates. Since version 2.0.0, Tim added `isBefore()` and `isAfter()` for date comparison.

Since there's no `isBetween()` method, I thought this would work:

```
var date = moment("15/02/2013", "DD/MM/YYYY");
var startDate = moment("12/01/2013", "DD/MM/YYYY");
var endDate = moment("15/01/2013", "DD/MM/YYYY");
```

if (date.isBefore(endDate) 
 && date.isAfter(startDate) 
 || (date.isSame(startDate) || date.isSame(endDate))
) { 
  alert("Yay!"); 
} else {
  alert("Nay! :("); 
}

I'm convinced there's got to be a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confident you wanted `isBetween` **`||`** `isStart || isEnd`?

Comment: Yeah, typo there, sorry!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can use [one of the moment plugin](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/range/) -> [moment-range](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range) to deal with date range:

```
var startDate = new Date(2013, 1, 12)
  , endDate   = new Date(2013, 1, 15)
  , date  = new Date(2013, 2, 15)
  , range = moment().range(startDate, endDate);

range.contains(date); // false
```

Comment: how do you include the plugin?

Comment: You should just include <script src="/javascripts/moment-range.js"></script> after momentjs

Comment: date.isBetween(startDate, endDate); is much simpler and avoids requiring an additional plugin.

Comment: moment & moment-Range provides options to format date time while preparing ranges and then compare the dates for Contains / Within / Overlaps / Intersect / Add / Subtract.

if some one retrieving dates in some special format, then one can able to prepare date ranges inside array by converting those dates with required format and then we can compare.

Comment: For React after `npm install moment`, `import moment from 'moment';`

Comment: Is creating a range going to be more resource intensive than the answer below, using `moment.isBetween` ?

Comment: this will be helpful

``` const Moment = require('moment');
const MomentRange = require('moment-range');
const moment = MomentRange.extendMoment(Moment); ```

Answer (score 371):

In **versions 2.9+** there is an `isBetween` function, but it's exclusive:

```
var compareDate = moment("15/02/2013", "DD/MM/YYYY");
var startDate   = moment("12/01/2013", "DD/MM/YYYY");
var endDate     = moment("15/01/2013", "DD/MM/YYYY");

// omitting the optional third parameter, 'units'
compareDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate); //false in this case
```

There is an inclusive workaround ...
`x.isBetween(a, b) || x.isSame(a) || x.isSame(b)`

... which is logically equivalent to
`!(x.isBefore(a) || x.isAfter(b))`

In **version 2.13** the `isBetween` function has a fourth optional parameter, `inclusivity`.

Use it like this:

```
target.isBetween(start, finish, 'days', '()') // default exclusive
target.isBetween(start, finish, 'days', '(]') // right inclusive
target.isBetween(start, finish, 'days', '[)') // left inclusive
target.isBetween(start, finish, 'days', '[]') // all inclusive
```

More units to consider: `years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds`

Note: units are still optional. Use `null` as the third argument to disregard units in which case milliseconds is the default granularity.

[Visit the Official Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)

Comment: `x.isBetween(moment(a).subtract(1, 'day'), b)` seems to do the trick as well.

Comment: @ThisClark That's a good workaround; might I suggest another one with fewer function calls: `!(x.isBefore(a) || x.isAfter(b))`

Comment: What does `exclusive` mean?

Comment: @Batman Consider the list 1,2,3,4,5. Exclusively, 1 and 5 are not between the values of this list. Inclusively, 1 and 5 are between the values of this list. Left inclusive (same as right exclusive) includes 1, but not 5. Right inclusive (same as left exclusive) includes 5, but not 1.

Answer (score 34):

You can use

```
moment().isSameOrBefore(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array);
moment().isSameOrAfter(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array);
```

or

```
moment().isBetween(moment-like, moment-like);
```

See here : http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

Comment: Quick note: ``isBetween`` requires moment 2.13.0. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/

Answer (score 16):

I do believe that

```
if (startDate <= date && date <= endDate) {
  alert("Yay");
} else {
  alert("Nay! :("); 
}
```

works too...

Comment: This calculation always ignores the year. For example, If I give startDate ='05-01-2019', endDate = '05-31-2019' and date as '05-21-2017', it will give me result as "Yay", although it is false.

Comment: @AakashMaurya You are comparing strings, not dates. Make sure that you define your startDate/endDate as startDate=new Date("05-01-2019").

Answer (score 15):

Good news everyone, there's an `isBetween` function!
Update your library ;)

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/

Comment: True but `isBetween` isn't inclusive

Comment: Version 2.13.0 introduces exclusivity.   A [ indicates inclusion of a value. A ( indicates exclusion. If the inclusivity parameter is used, both indicators must be passed. `moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-10-30', null, '[]'); //true`

Answer (score 14):

Please use the 4th parameter of moment.isBetween function (inclusivity). Example:

```
var startDate = moment("15/02/2013", "DD/MM/YYYY");
var endDate = moment("20/02/2013", "DD/MM/YYYY");

var testDate = moment("15/02/2013", "DD/MM/YYYY");

testDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate, 'days', true); // will return true
testDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate, 'days', false); // will return false
```

Comment: any documentation link for this?

Comment: they introduced a small change in the 4th parameter on the new version, but it still works as the inclusivity parameter. here's the documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/#:~:text=Version%202.13.0%20introduces%20inclusivity

Answer (score 7):

```
if (date.isBefore(endDate) 
 && date.isAfter(startDate) 
 || (date.isSame(startDate) || date.isSame(endDate))
```

is logically the same as

```
if (!(date.isBefore(startDate) || date.isAfter(endDate)))
```

which saves you a couple of lines of code and (in some cases) method calls.

Might be easier than pulling in a whole plugin if you only want to do this once or twice.

Answer (score 1):

As Per documentation of moment js,

There is Precise Range plugin, written by Rob Dawson, can be used to display exact, human-readable representations of date/time ranges, url :http://codebox.org.uk/pages/moment-date-range-plugin

```
moment("2014-01-01 12:00:00").preciseDiff("2015-03-04 16:05:06");
// 1 year 2 months 3 days 4 hours 5 minutes 6 seconds

moment.preciseDiff("2014-01-01 12:00:00", "2014-04-20 12:00:00");
// 3 months 19 days
```

Answer (score 0):

According to momentjs docs for inclusion and exclusion we use 4th parameter which takes in [] or () or combination of both, bascially "[" means include and "(" means exclude  so bascially if we use left "[" or "(" this means date from will be included and if we use right "]" or ")" this means date to will be included

```js
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-12-30', undefined, '()'); //false
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-12-30', undefined, '[)'); //true
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-01-01', '2016-10-30', undefined, '()'); //false
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-01-01', '2016-10-30', undefined, '(]'); //true
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-10-30', undefined, '[]'); //true
```

So to include both we use "[]" in 4rth parameter.

[Momentjs Offical Documentation for **isBetween**](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/06-is-between/)

[image]