# Date of element with current date and assign unique ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of divs with unique dates that include the start of the week and end of the week associated with the content of the div. As seen below:

```
<div class="dinnersWeeks">
  <div class="startingDate">8/25/2013 12:00 AM</div>
  <div class="endingDate">8/31/2013 12:00 AM</div>
  <div class="weekLinkMenus"><a href="testweek.aspx">testweek.aspx</a></div>
</div>
<div class="dinnersWeeks">
  <div class="startingDate">9/1/2013 12:00 AM</div>
  <div class="endingDate">9/7/2013 12:00 AM</div>
  <div class="weekLinkMenus"><a href="generalweek11.aspx">generalweek11.aspx</a></div>
</div>
<div class="dinnersWeeks">
  <div class="startingDate">9/8/2013 12:00 AM</div>
  <div class="endingDate">9/14/2013 12:00 AM</div>
  <div class="weekLinkMenus"><a href="generalweek12.aspx">generalweek12.aspx</a></div>
</div>
```

And I'm stuck trying to identify if the current date falls between the start date and end date of each week's div.

```
$('div.dinnersWeeks').each( function() {
    sd = new Date( $(this).find( 'div.startingDate' ).text() );
    ed = new Date( $(this).find( 'div.endingDate' ).text() );
    currentDate = new Date();
    console.log(check > sd && currentDate < ed);
});
```

After that I'll assign an ID to the div that is the current week and the div that is next week.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you be against a solution that uses a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)?

Comment: Where does check come from :?

Comment: `console.log(currentDate > sd && currentDate < ed)` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. I think `checked` was a typo in your original code. I also added an example of changing the background colour. This could be easily changed to set the `id` with your preference.

JavaScript

```
$('div.dinnersWeeks').each( function() {
    sd = new Date( $(this).find( 'div.startingDate' ).text() );
    ed = new Date( $(this).find( 'div.endingDate' ).text() );
    currentDate = new Date();
    if(currentDate > sd && currentDate < ed) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red'); 
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/markwylde/4wuwZ/

Just on a side note, if you are wanting to do a lot of date related tasks in this project I would look into the moment.js framework, or one like it. There's a nice [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897571/moment-js-date-between-dates) post over here explaining a tidy way you could do the above using it:

Comment: +1 for [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). The above happens to work in Chrome, Firefox, and IE 10, but browser support for parsing dates from a string is often inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're outputting the HTML with a server side language?  If that's the case, I would just add an attribute to the div with the Unix time and run the comparators off of that.  I'm sure there's a library to do date comparisons in jQuery, but if you're not trying to do anything complicated you could just use Unix.

```
<div class="dinnersWeeks">
  <div class="startingDate" z-start-unix="3000392">8/25/2013 12:00 AM</div>
  <div class="endingDate" z-end-unix="3001394">8/31/2013 12:00 AM</div>
  <div class="weekLinkMenus"><a href="testweek.aspx">testweek.aspx</a></div>
</div>
```

Then:

```
$('div.dinnersWeeks').each( function() {
currentDate = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
console.log(check > $(this).find('div.startingDate').attr('z-start-unix') && currentDate < $(this).find('div.endingDate').attr('z-end-unix'));
});
```

Comment: You have the same problem as the OP: the undefined variable `check`.