# Getting dates between two dates returing wrong dates outside of specified date range

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which returns date between two given dates, however, I am getting dates outside of the specified range.

I need to return formatted strings like: `12/01/2015`or `01/01/2015`. Note the added leading zeros. If I enter a Date range like: `12/01/2015 - 01/31/2016`, I get a date beginning 11/01/2015.

How do I get only the code within the given rage?

```
var getDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
    var dates = [],
        currentDate = startDate,
        addDays = function(days) {
            var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
            return date;
        };

    while (currentDate <= endDate) {

        dates.push(('0' + currentDate.getMonth()+ 1 ).slice(-2) + '/' + 
            ('0' + currentDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + currentDate.getFullYear());
        currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1);
    }

    return dates;
};
```

Comment: why do you not use moment.js it's very easy to use,and it allow manipulation of dates with flexibility

Comment: If you have jQuery ui installed you can convert the dateobject to a string using: `$.datepicker.formatDate( "mm-dd-yy", new Date( 2015, 01, 12 ) );` (pass the date object in second param) this makes the code allot cleaner, and less confusing when playing around with dates.

Comment: I second the nomination of moment.js as a candidate solution. I've answered this question previously here - [Moment.js: Date between dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897571/moment-js-date-between-dates/29495647#29495647). If an additional library is not an option, I'd like to point out that you can just take the solution from them as it's an open source library.

Comment: I love the moment Framework. I am already using it with require JS in my app. However, I did not know I could do so much more than what I am already doing. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
dates.push(('0' + currentDate.getMonth()+ 1 ).slice(-2) + '/' + 
                ('0' + currentDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + currentDate.getFullYear());
```

to

```
dates.push(('0' + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' +
      ('0' + currentDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + currentDate.getFullYear());
```

First add `1` then prepend `0` and then `slice`.

Also you need to parse the startDate and endDate as dates using `new Date()`;

Complete Code should be like:

```
var getDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
  var dates = [],
    currentDate = new Date(startDate),
    endDate = new Date(endDate),
    addDays = function(days) {
      var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
      return date;
    };
  while (currentDate <= endDate) {
    dates.push(('0' + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' +
      ('0' + currentDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + currentDate.getFullYear());

    currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1);
  }

  return dates;
};

console.log(getDates("12/06/2015", "01/31/2016"));
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qp3ghwuc/)

Comment: Thanks!! I am going to take this as answer for the effort and since it was the original intent but I think I will be jumping on the `moment.js` train. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the moment library (http://momentjs.com). In that case, this function becomes something like...

```
var start = moment('2015-12-01');
var end = moment('2016-01-01');

var getDates = function(start, end) {
    var dates = [];
    while (start <= end) {
        dates.push(start.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        start.add(1, 'd');
    }
    return dates;
}

var dates = getDates(start, end);

console.log(dates);
```