# Checking if current time falls in a time range (24hr) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

This is not about dates, it's about time.

*Don't know how you could possibly confuse the two*

What I have do so far:

At the moment, I can work out whether the current time falls in time range as long as its not 00:00 (12AM) or later.

This is because my current if condition only looks at:

`current time > startTime and current time < endTime`

```
if (currentTime > startTime && currentTime < endTime) {
    green
} else {
    red
}
```

Please see the snippet I have included to better understand the issue.

```js
var shiftStartWorking = '00:00',
  shiftEndWorking = '08:00',
  shiftStartNotWorking = '17:00',
  shiftEndNotWorking = '00:00';

$('#current').text(moment().format('HH:mm'));

if (moment().format("HH:mm") > shiftStartWorking && moment().format("HH:mm") < shiftEndWorking) {

  $('#working').attr('style', 'color: green');

} else {

  $('#working').attr('style', 'color: red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div>Current Time: <span id="current"></span>
</div>

<br />

<div>
  <span>Working version</span> -
  <span id="working">00:00 - 08:00</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js: Date between dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897571/moment-js-date-between-dates)

Comment: That is for dates, this is for time. If you don't have something useful to add, please don't add anything. You just end up confusing people.

Comment: So you have a time range(min and max) and you want to know whether the **current time** falls in that range?

Comment: @SyamPillai - it's kind of like (min and max) but not quite. The (min and max) are also time as shown in the snippet. I need to check the current time against different work time ranges

Comment: How do you get your time entries from the back-end when the time goes over midnight? Day X 17:00 until 02:00 or Day X 17:00 until 24:00 and Day Y 00:00 until 02:00?

Comment: Yes, the time entries are coming from the back end. I have multiple time ranges, I need to some how take into account that some time ranges will be equal to or greater than midnight. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Using moment, you can compare moment objects instead of strings. You can check if the current time is inside your range using [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) function.

**Edit:**

Moment objects represent a given date (date & time), anyway parsing string as shown in my snippet (passing only time values) creates an moment object for the current day. You can use those object for comparison since they all refer to the same day (by construction).

**Edit #2:**
I have added a check on relationship between start and end date to handle the case you mentioned in the comment. I previous answer was incomplete.

**Edit #3:**
Created a function to do comparison.

Here an updated version of your snippet:

```js
function isNowBetweenTime(startTime, endTime){
  // Creating moment objects for the current day at the given time
  var startMom = moment(startTime, 'HH:mm');
  var endMom   = moment(endTime, 'HH:mm');
  
  if ( startMom.isAfter(endMom) ){
    endMom.add(1, 'd');
  }
  
  return moment().isBetween(startMom, endMom);
}

var shiftStartWorking = '16:00',
  shiftEndWorking = '23:00',
  shiftStartNotWorking = '17:00',
  shiftEndNotWorking ='00:00';

$('#current').text(moment().format('HH:mm'));

if( isNowBetweenTime(shiftStartWorking, shiftEndWorking) ) {
  $('#working').attr('style', 'color: green');
} else {
  $('#working').attr('style', 'color: red');
}

if( isNowBetweenTime(shiftStartNotWorking, shiftEndNotWorking) ){
  $('#notWorking').attr('style', 'color: green');
} else {
  $('#notWorking').attr('style', 'color: red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div>Current Time: <span id="current"></span>
</div>

<br />

<div>
  <span>Working version</span> -
  <span id="working">16:00 - 23:00</span>
</div>

<br />

<div>
  <span>Non Working version</span> -
  <span id="notWorking">17:00 - 00:00</span>
</div>
```

Comment: After reading the documentation, isBetween is used for dates not time which is what I need

Comment: @edward I've edited my answer trying to explain why, in my opinion, you can still use `isBetween` in your usecase.

Comment: I really appreciate the help but, I think this might still be an issue. For example: let's say that the time range is 17:00 - 01:00 and the current time is 19:00. This should be true, would this case also work with your solution?

Comment: @VincenzoC it is probably safer to use a fixed date instead of implicitely rely on the constructor date (e.g. if you run the script at midnight) @ edward you should always compare times together with a date. What happens, if somebody works over midnight?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 This is my exact issue, I'm not getting a correct reading because others are working over midnight. How can I get around this?

Comment: At the moment I don't get the issue you are pointing out in the comments. Anyway feel free to edit my answer or create a better one starting from this one.

Comment: I've edited again (on mobile) my answer, see if it works for all your cases

Comment: I cannot add 1 day if the time goes over 00:00. I need a more compatible check in the if statement. Thanks for the help though