# See if current date is between some months with momentJs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using Moment.js to manipulate date format in my application and I would like to know how could I see if a my current date is between 31/08 and 30/09 (day/month) of the same year.

For example :

- If my current date is : 15/09/**2016** -> then the algorithm should compare 15/09/**2016** with 31/08/**2016**and 30/09/**2016** and see if it's between those dates.
- If my current date is : 15/09/**2018** -> then the algorithm should compare 15/09/**2018** with 31/08/**2018** and 30/09/**2018** and see if it's between those dates.

Comment: have a look a this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14897571/2496648), there are two proposed solutions. One with a plugin of momentjs as well as `isBetween` function available in versions 2.9+

Comment: I knew about the function isBetween. But you have to specify all the date, including the **year**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems simple enough:

```
var isInRange = date.month() === 8 || (date.month() === 7 && date.date() === 31)
```

Note that months are indexed from 0.