# How to use Moment.JS to check whether a timestamp is between 2 other timestamps

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, momentjs

I have the following JSON array (note these are only the 5th and 6th elements of the array):

```
[   
{ 
    Day: 'Mon',
    EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:00:00\'}',
    StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 16:30:00\'}',
    courseName: 'Computer Science 250: Introduction to Website Design',
    Credits: '4' 
},  
{   
    Day: 'Mon',
    EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:30:00\'}',
    StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 17:30:00\'}',
    courseName: 'Math 220: Differential Equations',
    Credits: '3' 
}
]
```

The data in the array is sorted by the values of the 'EndTime'. When I try to check whether the end time of the object at i - 1 (18:00:00) is between the start time and end time of the next object (at i which if 17:30:00 to 18:30:00) I should get true, but instead the isBetween method returns false.

How can I fix this, I know I am making some kind of simple mistake?

Here is my code:

```
for(let i = 1; i < monday.length-1; i++) {

const year = '1970-01-01';
const format = 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a';

  var next_endtime = monday[i].EndTime.substr(16, 8);
  var next_starttime = monday[i].StartTime.substr(16, 8);
  var prev_endtime = monday[i-1].EndTime.substr(16, 8);

  var plesson_e = moment(year + 'T' + prev_endtime, format), 
      nlesson_start = moment(year + 'T' + next_starttime, format), 
      nlesson_end = moment(year + 'T' + next_endtime, format);

  var testbool = moment(plesson_e).isBetween(nlesson_start, nlesson_end, 'time');

console.log(testbool);
}
```

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897571/moment-js-date-between-dates

Comment: I guess it will never get any for loop run... if the array "monday" has length 2 then 1 < 2-1 is false...

Comment: Try changing your format to `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a';`

Comment: @GiorgioBozio thanks for that, will put a condition for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you pass to moment does not match your specified format :

```
const year = '1970-01-01'; // => see the '-', and the year is first
const format = 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a'; // => you put '/' and day first
```

Try changing the format value to:

```
const format = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a';
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ecr5ygz/)

Comment: Knew it was something simple, thanks a lot, it works now

Comment: Sometimes, two pairs of eyes are better than one ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the datetime or format, which you pass to moment JS, it works for me:

```js
const monday = [{
    Day: 'Mon',
    EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:00:00\'}',
    StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 16:30:00\'}',
    courseName: 'Computer Science 250: Introduction to Website Design',
    Credits: '4'
  },
  {
    Day: 'Mon',
    EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:30:00\'}',
    StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 17:30:00\'}',
    courseName: 'Math 220: Differential Equations',
    Credits: '3'
  }
]

const format = 'hh:mm:ss a';

var next_endtime = monday[1].EndTime.substr(16, 8);
var next_starttime = monday[1].StartTime.substr(16, 8);
var prev_endtime = monday[0].EndTime.substr(16, 8);

var plesson_e = moment(prev_endtime, format),
  nlesson_start = moment(next_starttime, format),
  nlesson_end = moment(next_endtime, format);

var testbool = moment(plesson_e).isBetween(nlesson_start, nlesson_end, 'time');

console.log(next_endtime, next_starttime, prev_endtime);
console.log(nlesson_end, nlesson_start, plesson_e);
console.log(testbool);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```