# Checking current time between two timing using moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am using `isBetween` function of **moment** to check if time is in an interval or not.

```
var currenttime = moment()
var endTime = moment(slotsTime.time, 'HH:mm').add(parseInt(slotsTime.duration), 'minutes');
var startTime = moment(slotsTime.time, 'HH:mm');

if (currenttime.isBetween(startTime, endTime)) {
    console.log('dddd', slotsTime.date);
}
```

But every time the condition is false. I searched hundred times, found similar solutions.

Please help me out!

Comment: Posible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897571/moment-js-date-between-dates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js: Date between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897571/moment-js-date-between-dates)

Comment: I am using moment. So Can you give me another suggestions?

Comment: It looks fine to me. Are you sure of the values of `slotsTime.time` and slotsTime.duration`?

Comment: check this [this](https://repl.it/repls/SubstantialUnfoldedDriver) and clarify again whats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem

```
if (currenttime.isBetween(startTime, endTime, null, '[]')) {
     console.log('dddd', slotsTime.date);
}
```

That tells momentjs isBetween function to include the start and end time as boundaries

The default of isBetween function does not include the start time, meaning if currentTime is exactly the start time (which in mm:hh format it is) it will return false.