# Use moment.js to figure out if a unix timestamp was within the last week

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How do i use unix timestamp to work out if an event was within the last week?

I tried

```
moment().subtract('weeks', 1).unix()<item.start
```

but it is returning unexpected results.  thanks so much

edit:  thanks so much for the question feedback here is an example of my response

1537858386
1540197758000

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the actual results are and how they differ from your expected results?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to answer the following questions: What are those results? What is the value of `item.start`? We need those answers in order to help you. Please read [mcve] for more information on what kind of information we'd like with these kinds of questions.

Comment: "unexpected results" as in "`.unix` provides seconds and `item.start` contains milliseconds", perhaps?

Comment: Just a hint: moment.js provides functions like `isSame`, `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `isSameOrBefore`, `isSameOrAfter`. Which are dealing with things like this. Have a look at the moment.js docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

Answer (score 0):

You can create the point of time which represents the lowest valid value as you did before. When you have this point in time, you can check with momentjs if a given date is older.

```
const weekAgo = moment().subtract(1, 'weeks') // This is the time to check

const ts = 1519945200000 // any unix timestamp. This is 2018-03-01
const m1 = moment(ts) // Use a unixtimestamp to create a moment object

const m2 = moment().subtract(8, 'days') // further test data
const m3 = moment().subtract(6, 'days') // further test data

console.log(weekAgo.isBefore(m1)) // true
console.log(weekAgo.isBefore(m2)) // true
console.log(weekAgo.isBefore(m3)) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer for [date range checking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14898451/6952155)

> You can use one of the `moment plugin` -> `moment-range` to deal with date
>   range:

```
 var startDate = new Date(2013, 1, 12)   , endDate   = new Date(2013,
 1, 15)   , date  = new Date(2013, 2, 15)   , range =
 moment().range(startDate, endDate);

 range.contains(date); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Will be using `moment.diff` function

Follow these Steps

1. Convert unix timestam to moment object
2. Format date
3. use `moment.diff`

   ```
   function dateDiff (date) {
       // date is unix timestamp date
       let d = moment(date);

       if ( d.isValid() ) {
           d.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

           // moment() gives current date-time
           return moment().diff(d, 'weeks', true);
           // If past date then result will be positive if future date then negative.
       }
       else 
          return null;
   }

   console.log( dateDiff( 1519945200000 ) );  // 30.648079404761905   // 30 weeks ago
   console.log( dateDiff( 1534395200000 ) );  // 6.755883640873016   // 6 weeks ago
   console.log( dateDiff( 1529945200000 ) );  // 14.113687873677248   // 14 weeks ago
   console.log( dateDiff( 1541945200000 ) );  // -5.7275819675925925  // 5 weeks in future
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As @be-ndee said it was just milliseconds vs seconds so i just edited it to

moment().subtract('weeks', 1).unix()