# Yup validate date between 01 01 1901 and current system date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I'm struggling with this problem since several hours.
I'm using Yup package for validation and I need to validate DOB between 01 01 1901 and current system date.
I have the following code:

```
  dateOfBirth: yup
    .string()
    .matches(
      /^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])([\/. -])(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/,
      DATE_OF_BIRTH_ERROR
    )
    .test('length', DATE_OF_BIRTH_ERROR, date => date.length === 10)
```

If someone has experience with Yup and can help me with this comparison, I will greatly appreciate.

Comment: care to explain what isn't working? what your errors you are getting if any? what output you are getting vs expected?

Comment: It's not really about Yup, more just javascript. Are you using a date library? e.g. moment (not recommended) or dayJS (recommended)? If so they both have a method which allows you to check between a range of dates e.g. https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/is-between

Comment: @StudioTime I'm using moment.js and the date is coming from the input DD MM YYYY. Why is not recommended moment.js ? I know it's widely used

Comment: Not related but Moment is old and bloated, even Moment say to not use Moment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moment.js: Date between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897571/moment-js-date-between-dates)

Comment: @StudioTime I used ```moment(date, 'DD MM YYYY').isBefore(moment())``` to match if it's past current date.. from what I see, seems that it's working. Thank you!