# How to get this week's data only from array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object, momentjs

I'm working on an algorithm that should return this week's data from an array of objects (includes data for the whole current month), data looks like this:

```
[
 {
  date: 02/01/2023, // date is in ms
  soldItems:10
 },
 {
  date: 02/02/2023,
  soldItems:7
 },
 {
  date: 02/03/2023,
  soldItems:40
 },
{},...
]
```

I need to get data for this week's days that are available (Monday-Wednesday, 2/6/2023-2/8/2023) like this:

```
{
  date: 02/06/2023,
  soldItems:45
 },
 {
  date: 02/07/2023,
  soldItems:30
 },
 {
  date: 02/08/2023,
  soldItems:5
 },
```

I know I can get days of this week like this:

```
Array.from(Array(7).keys()).map((idx) => {const d = new Date(); d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay() + idx); return d }

///returns

[
  2023-02-05T01:36:03.197Z,
  2023-02-06T01:36:03.197Z,
  2023-02-07T01:36:03.197Z,
  2023-02-08T01:36:03.197Z,
  2023-02-09T01:36:03.197Z,
  2023-02-10T01:36:03.197Z,
  2023-02-11T01:36:03.197Z
]
```

but I don't know how to extract the available days of the current week from the array of objects, for example we don't have data for 02/09/2023 (tomorrow's date), so I just need this week starting from Monday till available day in array(needs to be dynamic). Any help and advise is greatly appreciated

Comment: MomentJs have `isBefore`, `isAfter` and `isBetween` functions. Use this in your filter and it should return the data as per ur needs. Some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897571/moment-js-date-between-dates)

Comment: You can also try the moment date range plugin - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/range/

Comment: Since your dates are already in milliseconds, all you have to do is get the time value for the first and last days of the week and filter for vales in between. There are plenty of questions and answers on that already, no library needed.

Comment: @RobG I think that's the issue I'm having, not sure how to get the correct value for the first and last day of the current week, for example how do I get 2/6/2023(Monday) and 2/8/2023(Wednesday) values?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify the format of this week to 'mm/dd/yyyy' and use filter() on your data like this:

```js
data.filter(d => thisWeek.includes(d.date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your dates are expressed as time values (milliseconds since the ECMAScript epoch) then you just need to get the time values for the dates at the start and end of the date ranges, then filter on those.

It seems your weeks start on Monday, so to get any particular weekday in the week of a given date:

1. Get the weekday number of the date
2. If it's 0 (Sunday), make it 7
3. Subtract the weekday number from the date
4. Add the day number for the required day (where Mon is 1 and Sun is 7)

As code that is:

```js
// Return required day of week
// Week starts on Monday
// Day numbers: Mon = 1, Sat = 6, Sun = 0 or 7
// Returns: Date in week of date set to 0hrs on required day
function getWeekday(dayNum, date = new Date()) {
  // Copy input date so it's not modified
  let d = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
  // Set d to prior Sunday, then to required day
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - (d.getDay() || 7) + (Number(dayNum) || 7));
  return d;
}

// Return dates for start of starDay and end of endDay
function getDateRangeByWeekday(startDay, endDay, date = new Date()) {
  let s = getWeekday(startDay, date);
  let e = getWeekday(endDay, date);
  e.setHours(23,59,59,999);
  return [s, e];
}

// Get start of Mon and end of Wed in current week
let monWed = getDateRangeByWeekday(1, 3);
console.log(monWed.map(d=>d.toString()))
```

You can just compare the time value to a Date, they'll be coerced to Number. Or you can do it explicitly by comparing to `date.getTime()`.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/), which is pretty small and tree-shakeable. It makes this straightforward:

```js
import { eachDayOfInterval, format, startOfWeek } from "date-fns";

const data = [
  {
    date: "02 / 01 / 2023",
    soldItems: 10,
  },
  {
    date: "02 / 07 / 2023",
    soldItems: 7,
  },
  {
    date: "02 / 08 / 2023",
    soldItems: 40,
  },
];

const filterDataToWeek = (data, formatting = "MM / dd / yyyy", currDay) => {
  const end = currDay ?? new Date();
  const start = startOfWeek(end, { weekStartsOn: 1 });
  const daysInWeekSoFarArr = eachDayOfInterval({ start, end }).map((day) =>
    format(day, formatting)
  );

  return data.filter((i) => daysInWeekSoFarArr.includes(i.date));
};

console.log(filterDataToWeek(data));
// (2) [Object, Object]
```

Comment: An answer shouldn't rely on a library not mentioned or tagged in the OP. The dates are time values, there's no need to parse them.

Comment: Hm, disagree - it's merely an option :) My answer should form the base of logic; the few functions I recommend here are merely implementation details that make one's life easier. (Parsing is done per the OP's sample case)

Comment: The OP doesn't parse anything. The values are time values (i.e. millisecond offsets from the epoch), not timestamps.